# Catch tab change event by mouse clicking on the tab

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a `CPropertySheet` with several  tabs. I have a different `CPropertyPage` class for each tab. If user clicks on the one page (Tab) then that page gets activated. How I can know whether user clicked on Tab or somewhere else in that page?

[image]

I am trying to get that event(`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) in `PreTranslateMessage()` of the property sheet class.

```
BOOL CMyPropertySheet::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
  switch (pMsg->message)
  {
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
    // here I need to handle if user clicks on page (Tabs)
       // But this is invoking if user clicking  inside page also      

    }

  return CPropertySheet::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

I have no idea what to do I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You want to have a look at [`OnSetActive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zd196y3.aspx) and [`OnKillActive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2122ct0z.aspx).

They provide an example:

```
// CShapePage is the last wizard property page. Enable the Back 
// button and change the Next button to Finish. The "Finish" button 
// will have "Done" as its caption.
BOOL CShapePage::OnSetActive() 
{
   CPropertySheet* psheet = (CPropertySheet*) GetParent();   
   psheet->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_BACK | PSWIZB_FINISH);
   psheet->SetFinishText(_T("Done"));

   return CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
}
```

That is what I use. You can implement them from ClassWizard. Is there any reason that the **sheet** itself needs to know rather than the **page**?

Comment: These two functions have their own drawbacks. While handling page changes, based on some input I must have to close the property sheet and re-open it (like refresh kind of thing). see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . So that's why I need to handle the pages changes in  PretranslateMessage().

Comment: Sure. PTM to the rescue. 

Answer (score 1):

Use `TCN_SELCHANGE`

function body will be something like this

```
void CDlgName::OnTcnSelchangeFuncName(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    int nCur = m_tabSettings.GetCurSel();
    if(nCur == 0)        //first tab clicked
    {
        //your code
    }
    else if(nCur == 1){  //Second tab clicked
        //your code
    }
    else if(nCur == 2){  //Third tab clicked
    {
        //your code
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

This may be helpful for you.

Comment: I have property sheets and property pages. I don't how to convert them in to Tab control. I could helpful, if u can provide more code.